# How to align Material buttons with other UI elements

Tags: android, button, material-design

I have trouble to align default material buttons with other elements of the UI. In fact I have looked at the Android source code and the background for the buttons contains insets to be able to draw the shadow and deal with the elevation of the button when clicked:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
   android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
   android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
   android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <padding android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
             android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
             android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
             android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

So, I have the very basic layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#123456"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test button alignment"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#123456"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And as you can see, the left edge of the button is not aligned with the left edges of the other views.

[image]

So my question is, is there a way to get rid of these insets without loosing the shadow/elevation handled out of the box by default Android buttons to have the UI well aligned?

Thanks!

Comment: This should be possible using [optical layout bounds](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#OpticalBounds), but I've had trouble getting this to work specifically with material buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also hit area thing involved. Buttons have larger clickable area than the graphics.

Your layout already has padding, so the button will easily have space to draw shadow. All you have to do is to remove horizontal insets from button's background.

The general case is more complex. You should:

- remove insets from button's background,
- remember to always add some padding/margin around your widgets to leave space for shadows,
- extend hit rect to capture clicks in entire clickable area.

First two things are simple, the last point can be done using for example getHitRect():

```
 public void getHitRect(@NonNull Rect outRect) { 
     if (touchMargin == null) { 
         super.getHitRect(outRect); 
         return; 
     } 
     outRect.set(getLeft() - touchMargin.left, getTop() - touchMargin.top, getRight() + touchMargin.right, getBottom() + touchMargin.bottom); 
 }
```

Your case is also very easy to solve using Carbon (which does pretty much what I wrote - removes insets, adds custom hit rect):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carbon.widget.LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#123456" />

    <carbon.widget.Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="test button alignment" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#123456" />
</carbon.widget.LinearLayout>
```

[image]

And here's how it looks with debug mode on. Red lines show extended hit rect. Green lines are view bounds.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zielony for your clear explanations. I ended just by copying the android files for button backgrounds and removing the horizontal insets as you mentioned. By the way great library :-)

Comment: what is Carbon?

Comment: It's a MD compat library. I wrote it long time before Design Support Library was there. Carbon does two things: 1. It backports ripples, dynamic shadows, vector graphics, rounded corners, numerous widgets, etc. 2. It implements things, which are missing in general - full svg support, additional layout attributes, custom fonts, etc.See: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon

Answer (score -1):

please review the following xml, I added to value `android:layout_marginLeft="-4dip"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/te"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#123456" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/te"
    android:text="test button alignment"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-4dip"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#123456"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bu"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think that hardcoding negative insets is the best idea. It may backfire one day.

Comment: yes Zielony your answer is best option. great job with (carbon)